# Why are scrolling slow when the table is large? and How can we improve it without Plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I put 220,000 cells on the table and It works fine.

I set the height and the width and I put the scroll and the table scroll is very slow.

How can it be faster than now without Plugin?

Below HTML,JS and CSS code

```js
function a() {
  var text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    text += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < 22; j++) {
      text += "<td class='a'>" + j + "</td>"
    }
    text += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#table_body").html(text);
}
a();
```

```css
table {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: 4400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>adsad1</th>
      <th>adsad2</th>
      <th>adsad3</th>
      <th>adsad4</th>
      <th>adsad5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you mean 220,000 cells

Comment: can you read 220k rows on a page ? no! then why put 220k and not use pagination?